# jQuery trigger click (element.click()) on dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that with on('click') for dynamically created elements, I must first use a parent element that existed in the DOM For example `parent.on('click', child, function(){});`

However now my task is to trigger a click to a dynamically created button.

I tried `$('#button_' + id).click()` and `$('#button_' + id, '#parentContainer').click()` but they didn't work.

Comment: There's nothing special about dynamically created elements as far as accessing them in the DOM. If you don't post your code and don't explain what you mean by "didn't work", then you can't be helped.

Comment: OK thanks for the info I'll look for the issue somewhere else now that I know that the click() function shouldnt have issues with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

`.trigger('click')` instead?

```js
$("#container").append('<div id="parentContainer"></div>');
$("#parentContainer").append("<button>Test</button>");
$("#container").on('click', '#parentContainer button', function(){
   $("#container").after("click!<br>");
});
$("button").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The question is about **triggering** "click" events.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
$('#button_' + id).on('click',function(){
   //your click event
});
```